# Kubernetes (kubeadm) missing public certificates in containers for outgoing connections

Tags: ssl, kubernetes

I've setup a kubernetes cluster on my contabo (provider) server(s).
Everything is running great so far, till I wanted to access an external SSL domain from a container.

I was able to reproduce the steps by

1. Setting up a new server
2. Running `kubeadm init` on it
3. Run `kubectl run -i --tty test --image=tutum/curl --restart=Never -- sh`
4. Run (in the container)

   root@test:/# curl https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/directory -v

   - Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
   - Trying 91.194.91.220...
   - Connected to acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org (91.194.91.220) port 443 (#0)
   - successfully set certificate verify locations:
   - CAfile: none
     CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
   - SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
   - SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
   - SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
   - SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
   - SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
   - SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
   - SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
   - SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
   - SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
   - SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
   - SSL connection using ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
   - Server certificate:
   - subject: CN=contabo.at
   - start date: 2017-06-13 03:21:00 GMT
   - expire date: 2017-09-11 03:21:00 GMT
   - subjectAltName does not match acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org
   - SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org'
   - Closing connection 0
   - SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
     curl: (51) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org'

If I am running the same thing in a plain docker container like `docker run -it --rm tutum/curl /bin/bash` (also on the server) everything runs fine.

So this must be a problem with kubernetes.

Can someone help me to add the public SSL certificates to my kubernetes setup?

Thank you & regards
Dominik

---

// EDIT 1

After some further investigations I edited my /etc/resolv.conf that it only contains the Google nameservers.

But this is not the issue.

Everything works until I join another node on my network like:
`kubeadm join --token db8341.36b4c997b2681683 1.2.3.4:6443`

Then it stops working. I am using the weave network / same problem with calico.

---

// EDIT 2

I added a full code example from my tests:

```
 root@sh0k:~# kubectl get nodes -o wide
    NAME         STATUS    AGE       VERSION   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION
    c1.sh0k.de   Ready     1m        v1.7.1    <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS   4.4.0-83-generic
    sh0k.de      Ready     9m        v1.7.1    <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS   4.4.0-83-generic
    root@sh0k:~# kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide
    NAMESPACE     NAME                              READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP              NODE
    kube-system   etcd-sh0k.de                      1/1       Running   1          8m        5.189.140.74    sh0k.de
    kube-system   kube-apiserver-sh0k.de            1/1       Running   1          8m        5.189.140.74    sh0k.de
    kube-system   kube-controller-manager-sh0k.de   1/1       Running   1          8m        5.189.140.74    sh0k.de
    kube-system   kube-dns-2425271678-n3cgv         3/3       Running   3          9m        10.40.0.22      sh0k.de
    kube-system   kube-proxy-fw41z                  1/1       Running   0          1m        213.136.88.53   c1.sh0k.de
    kube-system   kube-proxy-wtd7l                  1/1       Running   1          9m        5.189.140.74    sh0k.de
    kube-system   kube-scheduler-sh0k.de            1/1       Running   1          8m        5.189.140.74    sh0k.de
    kube-system   weave-net-8tts6                   2/2       Running   1          1m        213.136.88.53   c1.sh0k.de
    kube-system   weave-net-smfpn                   2/2       Running   3          5m        5.189.140.74    sh0k.de
    (reverse-i-search)`': ^C
    root@sh0k:~# kubectl run -i --tty test --image=tutum/curl --restart=Never -- sh
    If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.

    # curl -v https://www.google.com
    * Rebuilt URL to: https://www.google.com/
    * Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
    * Could not resolve host: www.google.com
    * Closing connection 0
    curl: (6) Could not resolve host: www.google.com
    # exit
    root@sh0k:~# kubectl -n kube-system logs kube-dns-2425271678-n3cgv kubedns   
    I0719 05:36:25.156505       7 dns.go:48] version: 1.14.3-4-gee838f6
    I0719 05:36:25.174462       7 server.go:70] Using configuration read from directory: /kube-dns-config with period 10s
    I0719 05:36:25.175247       7 server.go:113] FLAG: --alsologtostderr="false"
    I0719 05:36:25.175810       7 server.go:113] FLAG: --config-dir="/kube-dns-config"
    I0719 05:36:25.176361       7 server.go:113] FLAG: --config-map=""
    I0719 05:36:25.176918       7 server.go:113] FLAG: --config-map-namespace="kube-system"
    I0719 05:36:25.177459       7 server.go:113] FLAG: --config-period="10s"
    I0719 05:36:25.177509       7 server.go:113] FLAG: --dns-bind-address="0.0.0.0"
    I0719 05:36:25.177555       7 server.go:113] FLAG: --dns-port="10053"
    I0719 05:36:25.177593       7 server.go:113] FLAG: --domain="cluster.local."
    I0719 05:36:25.177643       7 server.go:113] FLAG: --federations=""
    I0719 05:36:25.177674       7 server.go:113] FLAG: --healthz-port="8081"
    I0719 05:36:25.177702       7 server.go:113] FLAG: --initial-sync-timeout="1m0s"
    I0719 05:36:25.177748       7 server.go:113] FLAG: --kube-master-url=""
    I0719 05:36:25.177779       7 server.go:113] FLAG: --kubecfg-file=""
    I0719 05:36:25.177806       7 server.go:113] FLAG: --log-backtrace-at=":0"
    I0719 05:36:25.177858       7 server.go:113] FLAG: --log-dir=""
    I0719 05:36:25.177887       7 server.go:113] FLAG: --log-flush-frequency="5s"
    I0719 05:36:25.177933       7 server.go:113] FLAG: --logtostderr="true"
    I0719 05:36:25.177961       7 server.go:113] FLAG: --nameservers=""
    I0719 05:36:25.177988       7 server.go:113] FLAG: --stderrthreshold="2"
    I0719 05:36:25.178017       7 server.go:113] FLAG: --v="2"
    I0719 05:36:25.178057       7 server.go:113] FLAG: --version="false"
    I0719 05:36:25.178086       7 server.go:113] FLAG: --vmodule=""
    I0719 05:36:25.178447       7 server.go:176] Starting SkyDNS server (0.0.0.0:10053)
    I0719 05:36:25.179197       7 server.go:198] Skydns metrics enabled (/metrics:10055)
    I0719 05:36:25.179209       7 dns.go:147] Starting endpointsController
    I0719 05:36:25.179215       7 dns.go:150] Starting serviceController
    I0719 05:36:25.179327       7 logs.go:41] skydns: ready for queries on cluster.local. for tcp://0.0.0.0:10053 [rcache 0]
    I0719 05:36:25.179347       7 logs.go:41] skydns: ready for queries on cluster.local. for udp://0.0.0.0:10053 [rcache 0]
    I0719 05:36:25.679413       7 dns.go:171] Initialized services and endpoints from apiserver
    I0719 05:36:25.679440       7 server.go:129] Setting up Healthz Handler (/readiness)
    I0719 05:36:25.679451       7 server.go:134] Setting up cache handler (/cache)
    I0719 05:36:25.679460       7 server.go:120] Status HTTP port 8081

root@sh0k:~# kubectl -n kube-system logs kube-dns-2425271678-n3cgv dnsmasq
I0719 05:36:25.672456      20 main.go:76] opts: {{/usr/sbin/dnsmasq [-k --cache-size=1000 --log-facility=- --server=/cluster.local/127.0.0.1#10053 --server=/in-addr.arpa/127.0.0.1#10053 --server=/ip6.arpa/127.0.0.1#10053] true} /etc/k8s/dns/dnsmasq-nanny 10000000000}
I0719 05:36:25.672682      20 nanny.go:86] Starting dnsmasq [-k --cache-size=1000 --log-facility=- --server=/cluster.local/127.0.0.1#10053 --server=/in-addr.arpa/127.0.0.1#10053 --server=/ip6.arpa/127.0.0.1#10053]
I0719 05:36:25.889812      20 nanny.go:111] 
W0719 05:36:25.889917      20 nanny.go:112] Got EOF from stdout
I0719 05:36:25.890205      20 nanny.go:108] dnsmasq[51]: started, version 2.76 cachesize 1000
I0719 05:36:25.890251      20 nanny.go:108] dnsmasq[51]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt no-DBus no-i18n no-IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP no-conntrack ipset auth no-DNSSEC loop-detect inotify
I0719 05:36:25.890274      20 nanny.go:108] dnsmasq[51]: using nameserver 127.0.0.1#10053 for domain ip6.arpa 
I0719 05:36:25.890287      20 nanny.go:108] dnsmasq[51]: using nameserver 127.0.0.1#10053 for domain in-addr.arpa 
I0719 05:36:25.890294      20 nanny.go:108] dnsmasq[51]: using nameserver 127.0.0.1#10053 for domain cluster.local 
I0719 05:36:25.890687      20 nanny.go:108] dnsmasq[51]: reading /etc/resolv.conf
I0719 05:36:25.890706      20 nanny.go:108] dnsmasq[51]: using nameserver 127.0.0.1#10053 for domain ip6.arpa 
I0719 05:36:25.890715      20 nanny.go:108] dnsmasq[51]: using nameserver 127.0.0.1#10053 for domain in-addr.arpa 
I0719 05:36:25.890722      20 nanny.go:108] dnsmasq[51]: using nameserver 127.0.0.1#10053 for domain cluster.local 
I0719 05:36:25.890730      20 nanny.go:108] dnsmasq[51]: using nameserver 8.8.8.8#53
I0719 05:36:25.890740      20 nanny.go:108] dnsmasq[51]: using nameserver 8.8.4.4#53
I0719 05:36:25.891436      20 nanny.go:108] dnsmasq[51]: read /etc/hosts - 7 addresses
```

Comment: I think this is not about the IP address but the cert returned when you `curl https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/directory`. `subject: CN=contabo.at` should be `subject: CN=*.api.letsencrypt.org`. Can you also paste the `curl -v` results of your docker command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved, by executing this command:

```
kubectl -n kube-system get ds -l 'k8s-app=kube-proxy' -o json | jq '.items[0].spec.template.spec.containers[0].command |= .+ ["--proxy-mode=userspace"]' | kubectl apply -f - && kubectl -n kube-system delete pods -l 'k8s-app=kube-proxy'
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not getting the correct IP address for `acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org` DNS hostname.

Can you update your `/etc/resolv.conf` with external DNS server's IP and test the `curl`.

eg. Google's DNS server.

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: in all your host machine make sure `/etc/resolv.conf` has correct dns entry and resolves correct IP for `acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org`. if you make changes in your node, you need restart the kubernets process on that node. Then run your pods, from inside your container see your getting the correct IP for the `acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org`.

Comment: Already did that. I think that kube-dns is broken.
If I add the upstreamNameserver 8.8.8.8 in the kube-dns configmap it works again, but I cannot connect internally from a pod running on master -> pod running on node.

Comment: yeah, looks like DNS or overly network issue. Is all your kube-system name space pods are running state? also verfiy the log message for kube-dns pod

Comment: I've edited the main question, so that you can see my whole setup and test. 
As I already mentioned... everything works great with just one master/node, only if I add c1.sh0k.de it is having this issue.

Comment: I see you have nodes in different network address `213.136.88.53   c1.sh0k.de` & `5.189.140.74    sh0k.de`.  I haven't used  nodes in different subnet. usally we keep the cluster nodes in same subnet. Is there a reason you have two different IP for your nodes?